# SecKeychain load item

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keychain

I want to store SMTP-Data from my Mac OSX application using the keychain. I read the Keychain Services Programming Guide of Apple and wrote this method to store the data:

```
    - (BOOL)saveSMPTData
{
    OSStatus err;
    SecKeychainItemRef item = nil;
    SecProtocolType protocol = kSecProtocolTypeSMTP;
    const char *accessLabelUTF8 = [KEYCHAIN_NAME UTF8String];
    const char *serverNameUTF8 = [self.serverName UTF8String];
    const char *usernameUTF8 = [self.username UTF8String];
    const char *passwordUTF8 = [self.password UTF8String];

    SecAccessRef access = createAccess(KEYCHAIN_NAME);

    SecKeychainAttribute attrs[] = {
        { kSecLabelItemAttr, (int)strlen(accessLabelUTF8), (char *)accessLabelUTF8 },
        { kSecAccountItemAttr, (int)strlen(usernameUTF8), (char *)usernameUTF8 },
        { kSecServerItemAttr, (int)strlen(serverNameUTF8), (char *)serverNameUTF8 },
        { kSecProtocolItemAttr, sizeof(SecProtocolType), (SecProtocolType *)&protocol }
    };
    SecKeychainAttributeList attributes = { sizeof(attrs) / sizeof(attrs[0]), attrs };
    err = SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent(kSecInternetPasswordItemClass,
                                           &attributes,
                                           (int)strlen(passwordUTF8),
                                           passwordUTF8,
                                           NULL,
                                           access,
                                           &item);
    if (access) CFRelease(access);
    if (item) CFRelease(item);
    return (err == noErr);
}

SecAccessRef createAccess(NSString *accessLabel)
{
    OSStatus err;
    SecAccessRef access = nil;
    NSArray *trustedApplications = nil;

    SecTrustedApplicationRef myself;
    err = SecTrustedApplicationCreateFromPath(NULL, &myself);

    trustedApplications = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)myself, nil];
    err = SecAccessCreate((__bridge CFStringRef)accessLabel,
                          (__bridge CFArrayRef)trustedApplications, &access);

    if (err) return nil;
    return access;
}
```

Of course I also want to load them. My first try looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)loadDataFromKeychain
{
    uint32_t serverNameLength = 0;
    const char *serverName = NULL;

    uint32_t usernameLength = 0;
    const char *username = NULL;

    uint32_t passwordLength = 0;
    void **password = NULL;

    OSStatus err = SecKeychainFindInternetPassword(NULL,
                                                   serverNameLength, serverName,
                                                   0, NULL,
                                                   usernameLength, username,
                                                   0, NULL,
                                                   0, 0,
                                                   0,
                                                   &passwordLength, password,
                                                   NULL); // How do I get the ItemRef?

    return (err == noErr);
}
```

But this does not work, and I think I know why not. I don’t know how to get the *SecKeychainItemRef* for the *SecKeychainFindInternetPassword* method.

Maybe anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring `password` a `void **`, declare it a `void *` and pass `&password` for the second-to-last parameter.

You probably don't need the SecKeychainItemRef for what you're trying to accomplish.

By the way, have you tried using **Keychain Access** to verify the items are getting into the keychain?

Comment: This goes for `serverName` and `userName` as well. (And this is also how the questioner would get the item ref if he or she really needs it: declare a variable to hold it, then pass a pointer to the variable.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Declaring password the way you described fixed the problem. But i still don’t know how to get the item reference. I cannot hold it in pointer after creating it because I when restart the Application I just want to read out the item. So how do i search for the correct item?

Comment: @kober: Use `SecKeychainFindInternetPassword` and have it return the item to you, the same way you're already doing with `SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent`.

Comment: Using `SecKeychainFindInternetPassword` i don’t get the right item. I now use `SecKeychainItemCreatePersistentReference` to save my itemRef and `SecKeychainItemCopyFromPersistentReference` to get it.

Comment: @kober: Well, the code in the question searches for an item with no server name or username. You'll need to fill those in if you want `SecKeychainFindInternetPassword` to find the item you created with them.

Comment: yeah thats the point, i need to get all these information out of the item. But working with persistent references works for me.